# NullPointerException in java.lang.String

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, mysql-connector

The stack trace:

```
[#|2013-02-19T16:05:25.596-0500|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/PulseEngine/PulseEngine-ejb_jar/_PulsePU|    _ThreadID=103;_Th
readName=Thread-2;|java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.String.checkBounds(String.java:374)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:415)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SingleByteCharsetConverter.<init>(SingleByteCharsetConverter.java:153)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SingleByteCharsetConverter.initCharset(SingleByteCharsetConverter.java:108)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SingleByteCharsetConverter.getInstance(SingleByteCharsetConverter.java:86)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.getCharsetConverter(Connection.java:3505)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getStringInternal(ResultSet.java:5667)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getString(ResultSet.java:5544)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getFloat(ResultSet.java:2523)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ResultSetWrapper.getFloat(ResultSetWrapper.java:239)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.getObjectThroughOptimizedDataConversion(DatabaseAccessor.java:1267)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.getObject(DatabaseAccessor.java:1170)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.fetchRow(DatabaseAccessor.java:999)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processResultSet(DatabaseAccessor.java:723)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:621)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:253)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:264)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:646)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2611)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2570)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:420)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1081)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1040)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:392)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1128)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:485)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:773)
at enkia.pulse.indexing.SentimentAnalysisIndexer.insertSentiment(SentimentAnalysisIndexer.java:376)
at enkia.pulse.indexing.SentimentAnalysisIndexer.insertSentiments(SentimentAnalysisIndexer.java:355)
at enkia.pulse.indexing.SentimentAnalysisIndexer.clusterCategorySentiments(SentimentAnalysisIndexer.java:530)
at enkia.pulse.indexing.beans.SAIBean.ejbTimeout(SAIBean.java:120)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundTimeout(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:149)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:4058)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1832)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$100(EJBTimerService.java:108)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:2646)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I'm at a complete loss.  I tried changing back and forth between OpenJDK and Oracle JDK.  I'm on Ubuntu 12.10.  The project is using mysql-connector-java-5.1.13 as it's jdbc driver.

Any leads appreciated.

Comment: When this error happens: when loading your app or when executing some functionality (if is the last one, please show your code)?

Comment: What version of Java? (eg. 5, 6, 7...)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas It's OpenJDK 7, apparent from the line numbers.

Comment: Looks like the bug is in the driver (probably tickled by some configuration either from the database or through system properties).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline:I think you are right.Seems to be related to the encodingName used to create the object.The fact that `checkBounds` throws a `NullPointerException` instead of a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is suspicious

Comment: @Cratylus Why? Those two could just be zero.

Comment: Thanks @Marko  I'm going to switch to Oracle Java and see if it still has the same line numbers.  I don't recall the line number changing when I switched before.  Is there a link to confirm that the two different ones have different line numbers for string?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik:Yes, I mean that the answer of @cjstehno is in the correct direction.`NullPointerException` points to `bytes` being `null`.

Comment: @user2088804 OpenJDK and Oracle JDK are almost identical in every respect except some small parts of implementation. The `String` class is definitely identical in both and it is certain that your problem is not caused by that.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the source for String:

```
private static void checkBounds(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length) {
    if (length < 0)
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(length);
    if (offset < 0)
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset);
    if (offset > bytes.length - length)
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset + length);
}
```

It seems to suggest that maybe you are passing in an array of bytes that is null. The third if statement is where the NPE is being thrown.

Maybe your result set has a null value (byte[]) that you're trying to convert into a string.

Comment: "you" in this case is the JDBC driver in response to a call to `getFloat`. (Looking like as it does some dodgy lazy initialisation to parse result string using whatever character set the database connection is using.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not about strings in the result set; it's about the code in the constructor of `SingleByteCharsetConverter`, which tries to instantiate `String` with a `null` byte array. This can be due to misconfiguration of the MySQL JDBC driver. Check if there's a system property you can set to the default character encoding of your MySQL database. If the encoding name is supposed to come from the database, then it could be eithar a bug in the driver or a missing piece of configuration at the database side.

Comment: I agree that it is related to encoding name, but I don't think that is the `null` object.It is not the `encoding name` that is the `bytes` in the `checkBounds`.

Comment: @Cratylus How did you reach that conclusion? Did you study `SingleByteCharsetConverter.<init>`? It accepts an encoding name.

Comment: I think this is definitely on the right track.  I will update if a configuration change works/is possible.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik:Well I found this file searching a bit, but I am not sure the version I am seeing is the same used.Just google for `SingleByteCharsetConverter.java`. You'll see a source code version in one of the top links

Comment: @Cratylus I checked again, you are right. It's the internal static `allBytes` field.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik:+1.I think this is in the correct direction

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik:Yes, I saw that also.Can not understand how can this field be `null`

Comment: @Cratylus Since we are looking at God-knows-which version of `SingleByteCharsetConverter`, this may not be OP's version. And I don't find the actual `com.mysql` version of the file.

Comment: I tried setting an additional field on my connection pool for "characterEncoding" as "UTF-8" but the error remains.  I'm using GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5) and MySQL connector containing the offending SingleByteCharsetConverter is version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar Since setting a default didn't seem to work, I'm going to get a newer connector .jar

Comment: @user2088804 From the source code I'm seeing this error should never happen.

Comment: Downloaded MySQL connector version 5.0.8 from Oracle and same thing.  However, so this appears to be an issue with the single "Float" column since this is within getFloat() so I'm going to try to work around the need for that column or change it to a different datatype.

Comment: @user2088804 I'd be surprised if that solves it, but hey, who knows :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  No solution yet.  Now that I've gone back to a previous instance I was already using, glassfish will not even start with a bogus port error.  Today is not my day.